# No "Login using Google" option in Android app

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, login, google-openid

I registered this ID with my Gmail account, and logged in successfully via web browser. However, while I was trying to log in on the Stack Exchange app in my Android Phone, I don't see any option to log in with Google:

[image]

I was told that no user was found with my Gmail account. It is amazing that I can log in via web browser, but cannot do so with the same Gmail account via app. How can I do that?

Just to compare, here is a "normal" login screen of another user:

[image]

Where did the Google login go and how can I bring it back?

My app version is 1.0.73, phone is Coolpad 8150D with Android version 4.0.3, kernel 3.0.8.

Comment: Do you have more than one Google account? Did you remove some built-in apps from your device? Also, please include exact device you have and app version

Comment: I just have a Google account, and log in by click on the Google button via web. However, there is no Google button in app. And the app version is 1.0.73.My phone is Coolpad 8150D with android version 4.0.3 and a kernal version 3.0.8.

Comment: Weird. Can you take screenshot of your login screen? That is what I have: http://i.stack.imgur.com/MJLzF.png

Comment: That is:[link](http://img.vim-cn.com/32/6624e357af70da30631c563a702e804c6cc68b.png)

Comment: So weird. I know that Facebook login requires the facebook app to be installed, so probably it means Google login also needs some app. Did you remove anything from your phone? Do you have google app(s) on it? (being android those come pre-installed, that's why it's so weird)

Comment: Anyway, this explains why you can't login, the Stack Exchange is totally different OpenID provider, the username and password there are **not** your gmail user/password

Comment: Originally, there is no google apps(s) or play store installed on my phone, when I bought it. There is only one application source called Coolpad Store, which have nothing in common with google. And time passed, the Coolpad Store refuses to work because it alarm that the version is too old to use and I have to update it. However, after I updating it, it can not run! I click on the Coolpad Store, then the screen become black. After a few minutes, the Android OS alarm a message reading there is no response to this application and ask me whether to kill it.

Comment: I have called the provider however, they said this kind of phone is out of date and is not maintained now. I once asked them whether I can install the google store, but they say it is not their business.

Comment: I have called the provider however, they said this kind of phone is out of date and is not maintained now. I once asked them whether I can install the google store, but they say it is not their business. So, I tried to install the Play Store 3 month age, and succeed. However, I cannot run the Play Store. After I clicking on it, there is a fast flash with dark screen and the OS alarmed my that the Play Store has terminated. I tried a few times, but ended up in the same situation.

Comment: So I fear you have to get new device with Google app on it in order to login via Google.

Comment: One week age, I have tried to install the newest Google, however, I found is amazing that I can not install anything from the online store.

Comment: Ok, but I still hope that the stack overflow can allow Google users get an additional local ID with the same account, and log in without any other account provider.

Comment: Doubt it is possible, but let's hope a dev come over and clarifies this.

Comment: Okay, i will try.

Comment: I believe, at the very least, you're going to need to install Google Play services to get most Google apps to work on your device.

Comment: I once have installed Google Play, but it can not work. I clicked on the Google Play app and the OS told me it was ternimated one second latter.

Comment: Have the same issue. Just flashed Android 6 on my Nexus 5 and I can use every google app and have play services installed but there is no login with google button :(

Comment: @WarrenFaith I'm on Android 6.0 as well. I needed to grant permissions to the SE app in order for the google login to appear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been fixed as of version 1.0.83, which went live February 12, 2016. Sorry I forgot to update the bug report about it. It was due to Android 6.0's new permissions model, which required us to completely overhaul how we did Google login in the app.

Answer (score 35):

I am running Android 6.0 and I needed to grant the Stack Exchange application access to my contacts for the Google login to appear:

Settings - Apps - Stack Exchange - Permissions - Contacts

[image: SE app permissions]

Comment: Worked for me - this is clearly a bug with the app not fully supporting android 6.0's new permissions set up.

Comment: That's terrible UX. Spent awhile trying to figure this out while setting up my new 6P. This did work but the button should always be showing, considering it's an android phone and pretty much requires a google account to function to an acceptable standard. Utterly peculiar that they upgraded to supporting Android 6.0 and didn't bother to ask for permissions, they are synonymous. Anyway I won't turn this into a rant.

Comment: It has been fixed since then. As of 1.0.81, the app will prompt user to allow accessing the contact on Android M.